# Galaxy S3 google play not working

Tags: google-play, galaxy

My girlfriends Galaxy S3 is not letting her access Google Play Store on the device. She Has tried all of the conventional means of getting things fixed clearing data / cache / force stopping all to no avail.

Any other options that do not involve resting the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is from [this link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-inspire-4g/246409-cant-access-google-play-market.html):

> 4 Simple steps. Set Date, Clear Play Store, Clear Google Framework, Reboot.

---

[Another link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/268695-google-play-store-isnt-working.html)

> If nothing works, try removing your Google account, then signing in again.
>
> Settings ---> Google ---> Tap on your email address ---> Tap on the three dots at the top-right corner ---> Tap on "Remove account".

---

Check out this [too](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/03/07/3-ways-to-get-google-play-store-now-on-your-android-device/).

> From the home screen, hit the menu button, and go to settings. Next go to applications, and then manage applications and click on the all tab at the top. Scroll down to Market and clear your data and cache. Once you open Android Market, you’ll be prompted to accept the new terms and conditions of Google Play and then the app will update itself.
>
> Download the APK from the Google Play Store, which was provided on Android-centric blog Droid-life. You can download the APK from MediaFire. Installing the APK would replace the Android Market app.

---

Again another [link](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/698001-google-play-app-wont-open.html)

> 1. Turn off the device.
> 2. Press and hold the **Volume Up** key, **Home** key, and **Power** key at the same time.
> 3. When the phone vibrates, let go of the **buttons**.
> 4. When the Android System Recovery screen appears, let go of the Volume Up and Home keys.
> 5. Press the **Volume Down** key to move to and highlight **wipe cache partition**.
> 6. Press the **Power** key to select and wipe the cache partition.
> 7. After the wipe is finished, go back up till **reboot system now** is highlighted and press the **Power** key to restart the phone.

---

Some video tutorials:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDc-JwbauAM
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRO3VAITias
- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/29473/ok-android-jelly-bean-reset-app-preferences/

Hope it helps you.

As said by [@CodeMonkeyAlx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580784/codemonkeyalx)

You can Factory reset it but if you have important data on your device then be sure to have a Backup . Here i have listed out some Backup apps. Some needs rooted device whereas some works for unrooted device too.

1. [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup&hl=en)
2. [Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)
3. [Super Backup : SMS & Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts)
4. [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup)
5. [Easy App Toolbox (Backup)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.goddchen.android.easyapptoolbox)
6. [G Cloud Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.genie9.gcloudbackup&hl=en)

Comment: We wound up just doing a factory reset but I accepted the answer due to it being in-depth and potentially useful to someone else in the future - Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for your solution i'll update my answer so it could help someone

Answer (score 1):

I was about to do the above, but then noticed that the playstore was disabled as to were some android components.

1. Go to applications
2. All applications
3. Scroll down the bottom of list and check to see if all android components are enabled- if not enable ones that aren't
4. Check to see if play store is enabled- if not enable

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the above. Maybe the problem was different. Tried rebooting with volume, power and home button pressed and clearing cache. No effect.
My phone is S3 middle east updated latest software version. I was trying to install some programs from Google play. The phone would lock up for long times between messages. It was very frustrating.
In the end I tried once more before resetting to factory. Managed to go to accounts, cancel Google account, and everything returned back to normal. It seems Google account was not communicating and kept on trying to do so in the back ground and failed repeatedly then locking while it was retrying.
Later I created the same Google account for backup and it still worked OK. 
Problem solved.
In short. Cancel Google account. Recreate Google account.
Hope it works.